# NOW() function in PHP

Tags: php, datetime, time, timestamp

Is there a PHP function that returns the date and time in the same format as the MySQL function `NOW()`?

I know how to do it using `date()`, but I am asking if there is a function only for this.

For example, to return:

```
2009-12-01 00:00:00
```

Answer (score 1210, accepted):

You can use the [date](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function:

```
date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
```

Comment: Note that you may need to use the [`date_default_timezone_set`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php) function

Comment: is there a function name now() in mysqli ?

Comment: No, he was referring to the MySQL (database) function, not PHP's mysqli object.

Answer (score 176):

```
date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
```

Look here for more details: http://pl.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: I'd like to emphasize how both You and @troelskn sent the same answer on January the 3rd of year 2010. at 17:08, but he still got ~800 upvotes more. Your answer submission was probably seconds apart from his. :) Thank You for writing it anyways :D

Comment: 9 seconds later (visible if you hover the "answered" labeled)

Comment: It prints seconds as three digits, i.e. `2022-11-30 12:00:250`

Answer (score 125):

With PHP version >= 5.4 [DateTime](http://php.net/datetime) can do this:-

```
echo (new \DateTime())->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

[See it working](http://3v4l.org/EABlV).

Comment: nice idea wrapping the constructor and formatting it right the way.

Comment: at last php started to copy from delphi and c# :)

Comment: this may be nice, but does not answer the question at all, it is not easier nor faster to do it this way

Comment: @Asped In what way does it not answer the question? It is a PHP function that "returns the date & time in the same format as the MySQL function NOW()", which is precisely the question.

Comment: @vascowhite - the question was if there is a specific function for this one purpose. so the answer is NO. all the other possibilities listed here may be working and yours is also nice, but does not help, as the guy asking already knew a way how to do it, but wanted an easier, single-purpose function, which yours is not :)

Comment: Asped, none of the other answers answered the question either. The chap posting the quesiton was already aware of the date() function, and they just repeated that. At least this answer brings something new to the table.

Comment: @pendrive No, because class member access on instantiation (e.g. (new foo)->bar()) support was introduced in 5.4. See the [release notes](http://php.net/ChangeLog-5.php#5.4.0).

Comment: Oh your right, did not think about instantiation, thought its about DateTime itself

Comment: replace echo with $variable = and this was exactly what I needed

Comment: is this better than `Date('Y-m-d H:i:s')` ?

Comment: I was able to use your solution to solve the "datetime now" issue that I was grappling with. I had to, however, remove "\" before "DateTime()", such that it became... "(new DateTime())->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');" Hope this helps. Thank you! Peace.

Comment: @masarapmabuhay Sounds like you're using an outdated version of PHP then. I'm glad my answer was useful to you.

Comment: DateTime is highly suggested for compatibility of syntax when using other supported features of the class (which is common). This helps improve the overall architecture of your code.

Answer (score 43):

Use this function:

```
function getDatetimeNow() {
    $tz_object = new DateTimeZone('Brazil/East');
    //date_default_timezone_set('Brazil/East');

    $datetime = new DateTime();
    $datetime->setTimezone($tz_object);
    return $datetime->format('Y\-m\-d\ h:i:s');
}
```

Answer (score 42):

**Short answer**

```
$now = date_create()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Read below for the long answer.

---

---

---

**The mimicry of the MySQL NOW() function in PHP**

Here is a list of ways in PHP that mimic the MySQL `NOW()` function.

```
// relative date
$now = date_create('now')->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'); // works in php 5.2 and higher  
$now = date_create()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'); // also works in php 5.2
$now = new DateTime('now')->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'); // syntax error!!!
$now = (new DateTime('now'))->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'); // works in php 5.4 and higher   
$now = date('Y-m-d H:i:s'); // Slightly higher performance, but less usable for date/time manipulations

// From Unix timestamp
// Using date_create() with a Unix timestamp will give you a FALSE,  
// and if you try to invoke format() on a FALSE then you'll get a: 
//     Fatal error: Call to a member function format() on boolean 
// So if you work with Unix timestamps then you could use: date_create_from_format().
$unixTimeStamp = 1420070400; // 01/01/2015 00:00:00
$y2015 = date_create_from_format('U', $unixTimeStamp, timezone_open('Europe/Amsterdam'))->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$y2015 = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $unixTimeStamp);
```

I think that `date_create()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')` is the best way because this approach allows you to handle time/time-zone manipulations easier than `date('Y-m-d H:i:s')` and it works since php 5.2.

---

**MySQL `NOW()` function**

The MySQL function `NOW()` gives the dateTime value in this format: `'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS'`. See here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_now.

An interesting fact is that it's possible to get the datetime format by running this query: `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'd%e_format'`, the result could be something like this:

```
Variable_name     Value     
date_format       %Y-%m-%d
datetime_format   %Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s
```

The variables up here are read-only variables. So you can't change it.

I guess the MySQL `NOW()` function gets it's format from the `datetime_format` variable.

---

---

---

**Advantages of using `date_create()->format()` instead `date()` summary**

The favorable facts of `date_create('now')->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')` over `date('Y-m-d H:i:s')` are:

- O.O.P.
- easier to handle time manipulations
- easier to handle timezones

**Disadvanteages of using `date_create()->format()` instead `date()` summary**

- `date()` performs slightly better

---

---

---

**Advantages of using `date_create()->format()` instead `date()` detailed**

Read on for the detailed explanation.

**O.O.P.**

The function `date_create()` is a constructor function for the `DateTime` object. The documentation of that Object gives the programmer a quick view that describes the possibilities.
Documentation: https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php

The function `date()` just gives you a string.

My taste for usability lies in O.O.P.

**easier to handle time manipulations**

`date_create()` accepts a relative date/time format (like `now`, `yesterday` or `+1 day`) see [this link](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php), example:

```
$tomorrow = date_create('+1 day')->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

`date()` accepts a relative date/time format as well, like this:

```
$tomorrow = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('+1 day'));
$tomorrow = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', (time() + 86400)); // 86400 seconds = 1 day
```

**easier to handle timezones**

When timezones matter then the usage of `date_create()->format()` makes a lot more sense then `date()` because `date()` uses the default time zone which is configured in `php.ini` at the `date.timezone` directive. Link: http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.configuration.php#ini.date.timezone .

It is possible to change the timezone during run-time. Example:

`date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Tokyo');`.

The downside of that is that it will affect all date/time functions. This problem doesn't exists if you are using `date_create()->format()` in combination with `timezone_open()`.

PHP supports major timezones. The funny thing is that it even supports the Arctic circle, and Antarctica. Have you ever heard about `Longyearbyen`? If not, then don't worry, neither did I until I read the official PHP documentation. Does it matter? Well... yes if you run an international e-commerce platform and do something bound to local time, for example: calculate delivery date-time.

```
$nowLongyearbyen = date_create('now', timezone_open('Arctic/Longyearbyen'))->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

See a list of all supported timezones:
http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php.

**`date_create()` VS `new DateTime()`**

The favorable facts of `date_create()` over `new DateTime()` are:

- Namespaces

**Namespaces**

If you work in a namespace and want to initialise a DateTime object with the new keyword, then you have to do it like this:

```
namespace my_namespace;

// The backslash must be used if you are in a namespace.
// Forgetting about the backslash results in a fatal error.
$dt = new \DateTime();
```

There is nothing wrong with this, but the downside of the above is that people forget sporadically about the backslash. By using the `date_create()` constructor function you don't have to worry about namespaces.

```
$dt = date_create(); // in or not in a namespace it works in both situations
```

---

---

---

**Disadvantages of using `date_create()->format()` instead `date()`**

The function `date()` has a slightly better performance than `date_create()->format()`. However, it's only visible if you would instantiate `DateTime` millions of times. Which might never happen in a real-life situation. However, here is the benchmark test:

```
$start = time();
for ($i = 0; $i <= 5000000; $i++) {
    $a = date_create('now')->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
}
$end = time();                  
$elapsedTimeA = $end - $start;
 
echo 'Case date_create(), elapsed time in seconds: ' . $elapsedTimeA;
echo '<br>';
 
$start = time();
for ($i = 0; $i <= 5000000; $i++) {
    $b = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
}
$end = time();                   
$elapsedTimeB = $end - $start;
 
echo 'Case date(), elapsed time in seconds: ' . $elapsedTimeB;
echo '<br>';
// OUTPUT
Case date_create(), elapsed time in seconds: 31
Case date(), elapsed time in seconds: 14
```

---

---

---

**Examples of `date_create()->format()`**

I use this approach for my projects if I have to fill an array. Like this:

```
$array = array(
    'name' => 'John',
    'date_time' => date_create('now')->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'), // uses the default timezone
    'date_time_japan' => date_create('now', timezone_open('Asia/Tokyo'))->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
);
```

Comment: Noting that `create_date` accepts timezone: `create_date('now', new DateTimeZone('Europe/Athens'))` - https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-create.php

Answer (score 28):

Try this:

```
date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
```

Comment: Right, if you waste characters like that, we're going to run out of them.

Comment: yep my bad the time() is actualy not needed

Comment: Actually, that would be a waste of 7 characters.

Comment: considering all the waste around here, I find it pretty shameful he used double quotes

Comment: You prodigals! Why don't you use strftime("%F %T"); and save a whole bunch of 10 characters?

Comment: Imagine all the characters wasted on commenting on the waste of characters!

Comment: This is the 3rd almost verbatim answer here. Where is the SO smackdown?

Answer (score 21):

I was looking for the same answer, and I have come up with this solution for [PHP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP) 5.3 or later:

```
$dtz = new DateTimeZone("Europe/Madrid"); //Your timezone
$now = new DateTime(date("Y-m-d"), $dtz);
echo $now->format("Y-m-d H:i:s");
```

Answer (score 19):

One more answer I find easy to use:

```
echo date('c');

// 2015-07-27T00:00:00+02:00
```

This is **ISO 8601 date (added in PHP 5)** which MySQL uses

### Edit

MySQL 5.7 do not allow timezone in the datetime by default. You can disable the error with `SQL_MODE=ALLOW_INVALID_DATES`. See the answer here for more details: *https://stackoverflow.com/a/35944059/2103434*. **But that also means that the timezone will be lost when saving to the database!**

By default MySQL uses the system's timezone, and as long as PHP uses *the same timezone* you should be okay. In my case CET / UTC+2.

That means that if I insert `2015-07-27T00:00:00+02:00` to the database, only `2015-07-27T00:00:00` will be stored (but that is the correct local time!).

When I load the time back in to PHP,

```
$importedDate = new \DateTime('2015-07-27T00:00:00')
```

it will automatically assume it's `+02:00` timezone since it's the default. Printing this will be correct again:

```
echo $importedDate->format('c');
// 2015-07-27T00:00:00+02:00
```

## To be safe, always use UTC on the server, specify it in MySQL and PHP, and then only convert it to your user's locale when displaying the date:

```
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
$importedDate = new \DateTime('2015-07-27T00:00:00+02:00');
echo $importedDate->format('c');
// 2015-07-27T00:00:00+02:00

$importedDate->setTimezone(new \DateTimeZone("America/New_York"));
echo $importedDate->format('c');
// 2015-07-26T18:00:00-04:00
```

Answer (score 16):

MySQL function `NOW()` returns the current timestamp. The only way I found for PHP is using the following code.

```
$curr_timestamp = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Answer (score 15):

Use [`strftime`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php):

```
strftime("%F %T");
```

- `%F` is the same as `%Y-%m-%d`.
- `%T` is the same as `%H:%M:%S`.

Here's [a demo](http://ideone.com/jy7AFI) on ideone.

Answer (score 11):

Or you can use [`DateTime` constants](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php):

```
echo date(DateTime::W3C); // 2005-08-15T15:52:01+00:00
```

Here's the list of them:

```
ATOM = "Y-m-d\TH:i:sP" ;               // -> 2005-08-15T15:52:01+00:00
COOKIE = "l, d-M-Y H:i:s T" ;          // -> Monday, 15-Aug-2005 15:52:01 UTC
ISO8601 = "Y-m-d\TH:i:sO" ;            // -> 2005-08-15T15:52:01+0000
RFC822 = "D, d M y H:i:s O" ;          // -> Mon, 15 Aug 05 15:52:01 +0000
RFC850 = "l, d-M-y H:i:s T" ;          // -> Monday, 15-Aug-05 15:52:01 UTC
RFC1036 = "D, d M y H:i:s O" ;         // -> Mon, 15 Aug 05 15:52:01 +0000
RFC1123 = "D, d M Y H:i:s O" ;         // -> Mon, 15 Aug 2005 15:52:01 +0000
RFC2822 = "D, d M Y H:i:s O" ;         // -> Mon, 15 Aug 2005 15:52:01 +0000
RFC3339 = "Y-m-d\TH:i:sP" ;            // -> 2005-08-15T15:52:01+00:00 ( == ATOM)
RFC3339_EXTENDED = "Y-m-d\TH:i:s.vP" ; // -> 2005-08-15T15:52:01.000+00:00
RSS = "D, d M Y H:i:s O" ;             // -> Mon, 15 Aug 2005 15:52:01 +0000
W3C = "Y-m-d\TH:i:sP" ;                // -> 2005-08-15T15:52:01+00:00
```

For debugging I prefer a shorter one though ([3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/FcWuJ)):

```
echo date('ymd\THisP'); // 180614T120708+02:00
```

Comment: Actually, it's `DateTimeInterface`, not `DateTime`

Comment: @AntonDuzenko [DateTime class](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) also implements _W3C_ and `DateTimeInterface:W3C` is only supported from v^8.0.1 ([online eval](https://3v4l.org/NQjoT)), unlike `DateTime::W3C` which supports below v8.0.0 until v5.4.0 ([eval](https://3v4l.org/8Ll5X)).

Comment: Not v8, v7 also has it

Comment: @AntonDuzenko not exactly, in [eval](https://3v4l.org/NQjoT#v7.2.0) below version 7.2.0 `DateTimeInterface:W3C` triggers a fatal error: "Undefined class constant 'W3C"... Since `DateTime::W3C` is not going to be deprecated, developers that work with multiple sites might just use this instead.

Answer (score 6):

I like the solution posted by user1786647, and I've updated it a little to change the timezone to a function argument and add optional support for passing either a Unix time or datetime string to use for the returned datestamp.

It also includes a fallback for "setTimestamp" for users running version lower than PHP 5.3:

```
function DateStamp($strDateTime = null, $strTimeZone = "Europe/London") {
    $objTimeZone = new DateTimeZone($strTimeZone);

    $objDateTime = new DateTime();
    $objDateTime->setTimezone($objTimeZone);

    if (!empty($strDateTime)) {
        $fltUnixTime = (is_string($strDateTime)) ? strtotime($strDateTime) : $strDateTime;

        if (method_exists($objDateTime, "setTimestamp")) {
            $objDateTime->setTimestamp($fltUnixTime);
        }
        else {
            $arrDate = getdate($fltUnixTime);
            $objDateTime->setDate($arrDate['year'], $arrDate['mon'], $arrDate['mday']);
            $objDateTime->setTime($arrDate['hours'], $arrDate['minutes'], $arrDate['seconds']);
        }
    }
    return $objDateTime->format("Y-m-d H:i:s");
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use the PHP date function with the correct format as the parameter,

```
echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
```

Answer (score 6):

My answer is superfluous, but if you are OCD, visually oriented and you *just have to see that **now** keyword* in your code, use:

```
date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime( 'now' ) );
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no built-in PHP `now()` function, but you can do it using `date()`.

Example

```php
function now() {
    return date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
}
```

You can use `date_default_timezone_set()` if you need to change timezone.

Otherwise you can make use of [Carbon](https://carbon.nesbot.com/) - A simple PHP API extension for DateTime.

Answer (score 1):

shortly

```
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

php advanced now  class extra addMinute addYear as such addHour etc ...

```
<?php /** @noinspection PhpUnhandledExceptionInspection */

/**
 * Class Now
 * @author  dılo sürücü <berxudar@gmail.com>
 */
class Now
{

    /**
     * @var DateTime
     */
    private $dateTime;

    /**
     * Now constructor.
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->dateTime = new DateTime('now');
    }


    /**
     * @param int $year
     * @return Now
     * @throws Exception
     * @noinspection PhpUnused
     */
    public function addYear(int $year): self
    {
        $this->dateTime->add(new DateInterval('P' . $year . 'Y'));

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @noinspection PhpUnused
     * @param int $month
     * @return Now
     * @throws Exception
     * @noinspection PhpUnused
     */
    public function addMonth(int $month):self 
    {
        $this->dateTime->add(new DateInterval('P' . $month . 'M'));

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @param int $day
     * @return $this
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public function addDay(int $day): self
    {
        $this->dateTime->add(new DateInterval('P' . $day . 'D'));
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @noinspection PhpUnused
     * @param int $week
     * @return $this
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public function addWeek(int $week): self
    {
        return $this->addDay($week * 7);
    }

    /**
     * @noinspection PhpUnused
     * @param int $second
     * @return $this
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public function addSecond(int $second): self
    {
        $this->dateTime->add(new DateInterval('PT' . $second . 'S'));
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @param int $minute
     * @return $this
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public function addMinute(int $minute): self
    {
        $this->dateTime->add(new DateInterval('PT' . $minute . 'M'));
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @param int $hour
     * @return $this
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public function addHour(int $hour): self
    {
        $this->dateTime->add(new DateInterval('PT' . $hour . 'H'));
        return $this;
    }


    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function get(): string
    {
        return $this->dateTime->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function __toString()
    {
        return $this->get();
    }

}


/**
 * @return Now
 * @throws Exception
 */
function now()
{
    return new Now();

}
```

using

```
  echo now(); //2020-03-10 22:10


echo now()->addDay(1); //2020-03-11 22:10


echo now()->addDay(1)->addHour(1); // //2020-03-11 23:10


echo now()->addDay(1)->addHour(1)->addMinute(30); // //2020-03-11 23:40


echo now()->addDay(1)->addHour(1)->addMinute(30)->addSecond(10); // //2020-03-11 23:50

//or u can use get method for example

echo now()->addDay(1)->addHour(1)->addMinute(30)->get(); // //2020-03-11 23:40
```

Comment: Why would anyone need an entire class for something that can be completely satisfied in one line of code?!?  If anything in this TLDR is of value, it is the right answer to the wrong question.

Comment: because  now is object everytime

Comment: The OP has only asked for a specific formatted date string.  Nothing more.  No date/time manipulations. This is the right answer to the wrong question.

Comment: Your edit has copied the suggested solution from 3 of the top 5 answers on this page.  You are contributing to page bloat (redundant content and out-of-scope advice) and this is not good for Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1):

In PHP the logic equivalent of the MySQL's function now() is time().

But time() return a Unix timestamp that is different from a MySQL DATETIME.

So you must convert the Unix timestamp returned from time() in the MySQL format.

You do it with:
date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

But where is time() in the date() function? It's the second parameter: infact you should provide to date() a timestamp as second parameter, but if it is omissed it is defaulted to time().

This is the most complete answer I can imagine.

Greetings.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get **time now** including **AM / PM**

```
<?php 
    $time_now = date("Y-m-d h:i:s a");
    echo $time_now;
?>
```

It outputs `2020-05-01 05:45:28 pm`

or

```
<?php 
    $time_now = date("Y-m-d h:i:s A");
    echo $time_now;
?>
```

It outputs `2020-05-01 05:45:28 PM`

Answer (score 0):

You might find this helpful

```
new \DateTime()
```

Comment: This ten year old question already had a number of answers that included this same code. What is new and different about this answer? Code only answers can almost always be improved by adding explanation of how and why they work.

Comment: This is nice to see if you're looking for the OO method of defining DateTime. Thanks Szymon

Answer (score -1):

The PHP equivalent is `time()`: http://php.net/manual/en/function.time.php

Comment: Wrong answer! `time() Returns the current time measured in the number of seconds since the Unix Epoch (January 1 1970 00:00:00 GMT).`