# error code 1292 incorrect date value mysql

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, mysql-error-1292

I have a table

```
`CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `PROGETTO`.`ALBERGO` (

`ID` INT(11) NOT NULL COMMENT 'identificativo dell\' albergo' ,
`nome` VARCHAR(45) NULL COMMENT 'Il nome dell\'albergo' ,
`viale` VARCHAR(45) NULL COMMENT 'Il viale in cui si trova  ' ,
`num_civico` VARCHAR(5) NULL COMMENT 'Il numero civico che gli appartiene' ,
`data_apertura` DATE NULL COMMENT 'Data di inizio apertura (inizio stagione)' ,
`data_chiusura` DATE NULL COMMENT 'Data di chiusura (fine stagione)' ,
`orario_apertura` TIME NULL COMMENT 'Orario di apertura' ,
`orario_chiusura` TIME NULL COMMENT 'Orario di chiusura' ,
`posti_liberi` INT(11) NULL COMMENT 'Disponiblità posti liberi ' ,
`costo_intero` FLOAT NULL COMMENT 'Costo del prezzo intero' ,
`costo_ridotto` FLOAT NULL COMMENT 'Costo del prezzo ridotto' ,
`stelle` INT(11) NULL COMMENT 'Classificazione in base al criterio delle stelle' ,
`telefono` VARCHAR(15) NULL COMMENT 'Recapito telefonico' ,
`mail` VARCHAR(100) NULL COMMENT 'Recapito e-mail' ,
`web` VARCHAR(100) NULL COMMENT 'Sito Web relativo all\'ente' ,
'Nome-paese` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Identificativo del paese in cui si trova l\'albergo' ,
`Comune` CHAR(2) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Identificativo del comune in cui si trova l\'albergo' ,
PRIMARY KEY (`ID`) ,
INDEX `Nome-paese` (`Nome-paese` ASC) ,
INDEX `Comune` (`Comune` ASC) ,
CONSTRAINT `Nome-paese`
  FOREIGN KEY (`Nome-paese` )
  REFERENCES `PROGETTO`.`PAESE` (`Nome-paese` )
  ON DELETE NO ACTION
  ON UPDATE CASCADE,
CONSTRAINT `Comune`
  FOREIGN KEY (`Comune` )
  REFERENCES `PROGETTO`.`PAESE` (`Comune` )
  ON DELETE NO ACTION
  ON UPDATE CASCADE)
ENGINE = InnoDB
```

When i try to run this query:

```
INSERT INTO `PROGETTO`.`ALBERGO`(`ID`, `nome`, `viale`, `num_civico`, `data_apertura`, `data_chiusura`, `orario_apertura`, `orario_chiusura`, `posti_liberi`, `costo_intero`, `costo_ridotto`, `stelle`, `telefono`, `mail`, `web`, `Nome-paese`, `Comune`) 
VALUES(0, 'Hotel Centrale', 'Via Passo Rolle', '74', '01-05-2012', '31-09-2012', '06:30', '24:00', 80, 50, 25, 3, '43968083', 'info@hcentrale.it', 'http://www.hcentrale.it/', 'Trento', 'TN')
```

***Error Code: 1292. Incorrect date value: '01-05-2012' for column 'data_apertura' at row 1***

What have i to  change? (i tried to change format's date from gg/mm/yyyy to gg-mm-yyyy, but nothing changed)

Comment: `data_apertura` field is `DATE` type and must be like `2013-01-31`

Comment: [Date and Time Literals](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-literals.html)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Insert date in the following format `yyyy-MM-dd` example,

```
INSERT INTO `PROGETTO`.`ALBERGO`(`ID`, `nome`, `viale`, `num_civico`, `data_apertura`, `data_chiusura`, `orario_apertura`, `orario_chiusura`, `posti_liberi`, `costo_intero`, `costo_ridotto`, `stelle`, `telefono`, `mail`, `web`, `Nome-paese`, `Comune`) 
VALUES(0, 'Hotel Centrale', 'Via Passo Rolle', '74', '2012-05-01', '2012-09-31', '06:30', '24:00', 80, 50, 25, 3, '43968083', 'info@hcentrale.it', 'http://www.hcentrale.it/', 'Trento', 'TN')
```

Answer (score 53):

With mysql **5.7**, date value like 0000-00-00 00:00:00 is not allowed.

If you want to allow it, you have to update your **my.cnf** like:

```
sudo nano /etc/mysql/my.cnf
```

find

```
[mysqld]
```

Add after:

```
sql_mode="NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"
```

Restart mysql service:

```
sudo service mysql restart
```

Done!

Comment: For windows it's my.ini

Comment: Thank you you helped me a lot, especially when i am working on legacy code with new config

Comment: I had to add the line to `/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf` instead. So `sudo nano /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf`

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same issue in Workbench plus insert query from C# application. 
In my case using ISO format solve the issue

```
string value = date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
```

Answer (score 1):

I happened to be working in localhost , in windows 10, using [WAMP](http://www.wampserver.com/en/), as it turns out, Wamp has a really accessible configuration interface to change the MySQL configuration. You just need to go to the Wamp panel, then to MySQL, then to settings and change the mode to sql-mode: none.(essentially disabling the strict mode) The following picture illustrates this.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

An update. Dates of the form '2019-08-00' will trigger the same error. Adding the lines:

```
[mysqld]

sql_mode="NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"
```

to `mysql.cnf` fixes this too. Inserting malformed dates now generates warnings for values out of range but does insert the data.

Answer (score 0):

Just an update of [@Sinan Eldem](https://stackoverflow.com/users/895239/sinan-eldem)'s answer:

Since MySQL 8.0 the ***sql_mode***='*NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER*' is **deprecated** ([source](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-nutshell.html#mysql-nutshell-deprecations)) and should be removed from the line, otherwise it will result in error reading sql_mode and failure starting mysqld.

If using MySQL 8.0+ add the following line instead:

```
[mysqld]

sql_mode="NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"
```