# Incorrect datetime value Database Error Number: 1292

Tags: php, mysql, database, datetime

**Incorrect datetime value 0000-00-00 00:00:00 +0000 Database Error Number: 1292**

Hi Everyone I'm having a problem a with a server upgrade done by my hosting company and I'm trying to understand what is occurring so i can fix the problem

My sever has recently been upgraded to Server version: 5.6.17 and I'm getting errors all over the place saying my datetime value is incorrect?

It seem to be add +0000 to the end of the datetime but I'm not sure why. This used to work perfectly fine on 5.5 but a recent upgrade has affected how my timestamps work

```
Error Number: 1292

Incorrect datetime value: '2014-04-02 08:49:43 +0000' for column 'created' at row 1

INSERT INTO `activitylog` (`tablename`, `row`, `user_id`, `description`, `action`, `private`,`created`) VALUES ('user', '1', '1', 'People', 'Updated', 0, '2014-04-02 08:49:43 +0000')
```

If I modify this sql query without +0000 it works?

It affects anything that is a type of DATETIME on my table.

Has anyone else had a similar problem and now what the solution is to get this to work. At the moment I'm thing I will have to change all my PHP functions to echo the Date/Time rather than me calling NOW() on the query string

Comment: possible duplicate of [error code 1292 incorrect date value mysql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14625191/error-code-1292-incorrect-date-value-mysql)

Comment: look my update:1 answer...

Comment: Note dupe, that is about invalid date formatting, this is about zero time.

Answer (score 33):

I discovered after upgrading to MySQL 5.7 that this error started occurring in random situations, even when I wasn't supplying a date in the query.

This appears to be because *previous* versions of MySQL supported dates like `0000-00-00 00:00:00` (by default) however 5.7.4 introduced some changes to the `NO_ZERO_DATE` setting. If you still have old data present when using a newer MySQL version, then random errors may crop up.

I needed to perform a query like this to reset all the zero dates to another date.

```
# If the columns supports NULL, use that
UPDATE table SET date_column = NULL WHERE date_column < '1000-01-01';

# Otherwise supply another default date
UPDATE table SET date_column = '1970-01-01' WHERE date_column < '1000-01-01';
```

Alternatively, you may be able to adjust the `NO_ZERO_DATE` setting, although note what the docs say about it:

> The `NO_ZERO_DATE` mode affects whether the server permits '0000-00-00' as a valid date. Its effect also depends on whether strict SQL mode is enabled.
>
> - If this mode is not enabled, '0000-00-00' is permitted and inserts produce no warning.
> - If this mode is enabled, '0000-00-00' is permitted and inserts produce a warning.
> - If this mode and strict mode are enabled, '0000-00-00' is not permitted and inserts produce an error, unless IGNORE is given as well. For `INSERT IGNORE` and `UPDATE IGNORE`, '0000-00-00' is permitted and inserts produce a warning.
>
> As of MySQL 5.7.4, `NO_ZERO_DATE` is deprecated. In MySQL 5.7.4 through 5.7.7, `NO_ZERO_DATE` does nothing when named explicitly. Instead, its effect is included in the effects of strict SQL mode. In MySQL 5.7.8 and later, `NO_ZERO_DATE` does have an effect when named explicitly and is not part of strict mode, as before MySQL 5.7.4. However, it should be used in conjunction with strict mode and is enabled by default. A warning occurs if `NO_ZERO_DATE` is enabled without also enabling strict mode or vice versa. For additional discussion, see SQL Mode Changes in MySQL 5.7.
>
> Because `NO_ZERO_DATE` is deprecated, it will be removed in a future MySQL release as a separate mode name and its effect included in the effects of strict SQL mode.
>
> *From http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_no_zero_date*

Comment: For me, the problem was that my `where` was incorrectly numeric when it should have been a string. I was trying to run `DB::table('contacts')->where('adId', 8888544168061)->update(['campaignId' => 8888626793661, 'adsetId' => 8888631774261]);` instead of `DB::table('contacts')->where('adId', '8888544168061')->update(['campaignId' => 8888626793661, 'adsetId' => 8888631774261]);`

Comment: it did happen to me after upgrading MySQL...but I don't understand your answer...

Comment: This is related to the `NO_ZERO_DATE` setting but there's more to the story, specifically how changes were made to `STRICT_TRANS_TABLES` and how it relates to the other "ZERO" settings as discussed in the release notes for [MySQL version 5.7.8](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql/5.7/en/news-5-7-8.html#mysqld-5-7-8-sql-mode). If you're on MySQL 5.7.8 or later, you'll probably find that removing `STRICT_TRANS_TABLES` from `SQL_MODE` solves the problem, as @RDVS mentioned in his answer.

Comment: Your query didn't update any record

Answer (score 31):

Ok, so I was having this same error. What I did to fix it was use these lines of code to query the database I was having issues with:

```
SELECT @@GLOBAL.sql_mode global, @@SESSION.sql_mode session;
SET sql_mode = '';
SET GLOBAL sql_mode = '';
```

The first line of code (SELECT) is to see what the current setting are for both 'SESSION' and 'GLOBAL'. Once you set them both to empty strings and run the select again, they should return nothing (be empty).

You may also need to use `SET SESSION sql_mode = '';` but this resolved the issue for me. Basically one of the settings in there was jacking up the way the date was coming into the database (I was getting it in a 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS AM/PM' format). Deleting `NO_ZERO_IN_DATE` and the other date option didn't help me.

My site is working like it's supposed to now. Hopefully this helps.

Comment: This solution worked for me (deleting `NO_ZERO_IN_DATE` didn't help). I had to drop and recreate the database, just in case that helps someone (I was trying to restore a database backup for a WordPress site)

Comment: I believe by setting `SQL_MODE` to an empty string, you're removing `STRICT_TRANS_TABLES`, which is the actual setting causing the problem, as @RDVS mentioned in his answer.

Comment: yous saved my life

Comment: SET SESSION sql_mode = ''; fixed it for me - thanks.

Comment: This was the final solution to my prooblem after i commited the rest like NO_ZERO_DATE  and hadnt worked.

Answer (score 13):

I was facing same issue.

I run below command and it worked for me.

```
SET SESSION SQL_MODE='ALLOW_INVALID_DATES'
```

Comment: This worked for me, but maybe not for the reason you might think. If I append `ALLOW_INVALID_DATES` to the existing `SQL_MODE` value, it doesn't fix the problem. But if I remove `STRICT_TRANS_TABLES` from `SQL_MODE` (as @RDVS mentioned in his answer) or just set `SQL_MODE` to an empty string, it does work. So I don't believe `ALLOW_INVALID_DATES` is actually doing anything in this case other than the fact that the value doesn't include `STRICT_TRANS_TABLES`.

Comment: This worked for me, and with the bonus of it being runnable within the context of a script to avoid having conf changes prior to making a connection.

Answer (score 11):

Short answer - `NOW()` in your query should work perfectly well with a MySQL `DATETIME` column.

Longer answer - I'm not sure how you ever saw `+0000` working.  The `DATETIME` column is formatted as `'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS'`.  When it comes to timezone differences, it's generally something you need to handle programmatically.  MySQL does convert local times to UTC and back again when storing and retrieving `TIMESTAMP` data - but it doesn't do this with `DATETIME` or other Date / Time columns.

Comment: This is the thing i haven't done anything. Like i said for ages I have been abale to get this working on Server version 5.5, Never had a problem but then a recent upgrade to 5.6.17 has thrown this error

Comment: I have the exact same problem. It has been working. Shared host probably update mysql, and now BOOM: Internal Server Error: 22007, 1292, Incorrect datetime value: '2016-09-12 18:30:00 UTC' for column 'xxxxxxx' at row 1... problem is I don't even have the 'UTC' in the string, it's a part of the mysql error message...

Comment: Exactly, I got this with a `timestamp` column type on an inherited code.  It was gone after I switched the column type to `datetime`.

Answer (score 9):

Original my.cnf had sql_model set as follows:

```
sql_mode=STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
```

I tried removing NO_ZERO_IN_DATE and NO_ZERO_DATE but it had no effect. But if I removed all terms (sql_mode empty) the error went away.

I went back to original sql_mode and thought I would remove terms 1-by-1 to see which one was cause. First attempt was to remove STRICT_TRANS_TABLES:

```
sql_mode=NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
```

No error.  So it appears that STRICT_TRANS_TABLES was the cause.

Comment: This is what worked for me. The changes made to `STRICT_TRANS_TABLES` and how it relates to the other "ZERO" settings are discussed in the release notes for [MySQL version 5.7.8](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql/5.7/en/news-5-7-8.html#mysqld-5-7-8-sql-mode).

Answer (score 5):

## Incorrect datetime value Database Error Number: 1292

The `TIMESTAMP` data type is used for values that contain both date and time parts. `TIMESTAMP` has a range of `'1970-01-01 00:00:01' UTC` to `'2038-01-19 03:14:07' UTC`.

The `DATETIME` type is used for values that contain both date and time parts. MySQL retrieves and displays `DATETIME` values in `'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS'` format. The supported range is `'1000-01-01 00:00:00' to '9999-12-31 23:59:59'`.

**you should use this type in: DateTime format**

```
INSERT INTO `activitylog` 
(`tablename`, `row`, `user_id`, `description`, `action`, `private`,`created`) 
VALUES 
('user', '1', '1', 'People', 'Updated', 0, '2014-04-02 08:49:43')
```

***https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-types.html***

***https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/datetime.html***

***http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=70188***

## update: 1

you should remove the `space` like your code `'2014-04-02 08:49:43 +0000'` and change the code like `'2014-04-02 08:49:43+0000'` as full query is following as:

```
INSERT INTO `activitylog` 
(`tablename`, `row`, `user_id`, `description`, `action`, `private`,`created`) 
VALUES ('user', '1', '1', 'People', 'Updated', 0, '2014-04-02 08:49:43+0000')
```

***look here  : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a2581/23099***

Comment: FWIW, this is caused by strict SQL setting: [`NO_ZERO_IN_DATE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_no_zero_date)

Comment: Just remove 'NO_ZERO_DATE,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE' from your my.cnf or my.ini

Answer (score 0):

I was facing similar issue but when I applied the code posted by @JedtheMarine as seen below, it resolved my case.

My case was specifically

> Error updating record: incorrect datetime value '2022-04-03 12:00:00 AM' for column 'XXX' at row 39

```
SELECT @@GLOBAL.sql_mode global, @@SESSION.sql_mode session;
SET sql_mode = '';
SET GLOBAL sql_mode = '';
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that this query works from [MySQL Incorrect datetime value: '0000-00-00 00:00:00'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35565128/mysql-incorrect-datetime-value-0000-00-00-000000) if you have this problem

```
UPDATE activitylog SET created = NULL
WHERE CAST(created AS CHAR(20)) = '0000-00-00 00:00:00';
```