# How can I change 0000-00-00 date to null?

Tags: mysql

When I run

```
UPDATE `my_table` SET `my_date` = NULL WHERE `my_date` = '0000-00-00'
```

it just says

> java.sql.SQLDataException: (conn=9310) Incorrect date value:
>   '0000-00-00' for column 'my_date' at row 1

Comment: Is the column nullable? i.e. defined as being not null in the create statement?

Comment: @FreudianSlip yes, it is nullable.

Comment: MariaDB [test]> select * from test;
| id | testdate            |
|  1 | 2018-04-26 08:29:54 |
|  2 | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |
|  3 | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [test]> update test set testdate=null where testdate='0000-00-00';
Query OK, 2 rows affected (0.01 sec)
Rows matched: 2  Changed: 2  Warnings: 0

MariaDB [test]> select * from test;
| id | testdate            |
|  1 | 2018-04-26 08:29:54 |
|  2 | NULL                |
|  3 | NULL                |

Does it work if you do it in the CLI?

Comment: **ERROR 1292 (22007): Incorrect date value: '0000-00-00' for column 'my_date' at row 1** 
@FreudianSlip Was able to select, but wasn't able to update.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14625191/error-code-1292-incorrect-date-value-mysql

Comment: actually - i bet it's this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37292628/1292-incorrect-date-value-0000-00-00/37297536

Comment: @FreudianSlip thanks. I got progress.

Comment: Dont forget to add your solution here - even if you answer your own question - it'll be useful for the next person.