# Laravel DateTime Invalid Input

Tags: php, laravel, date, datetime

SO, i want to store some dates in my database, but whenever i try to insert it i get:

```
Invalid datetime format: 1292 Incorrect datetime value: '2050-12-12 00:00:00' for column 'object_end'
```

However if i use for example `2021` as year, it works fine. Checking [MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/datetime.html) seems like it supports dates until year `9999`, so why am i getting this error? (if you need some code, feel free to ask, i'll edit the question with that code)

Comment: possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14625191/error-code-1292-incorrect-date-value-mysql

Comment: @AmeerSalahAldeen please check the error and you will see that is in the same format of the question you are referring to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your 'object_end' field is absolutely of type 'TIMESTAMP'

and according to mysql documentation:

The TIMESTAMP data type is used for values that contain both date and time parts. TIMESTAMP has a range of '1970-01-01 00:00:01' UTC to '2038-01-19 03:14:07' UTC.

to sole the problem, just change the column type to DateTime

please note that the fields 'created_at','updated_at' are generated as TIMESTAMP note DateTime
more details in:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/datetime.html

Comment: So in the next 18 years we have to change all the databases?

Comment: i think just updating mysql would fix that