# Why would a database work on one server, and only partially on another?

Tags: mariadb, database-migration, plesk

Sorry if this is a newbie question. I have been searching and can't seem to figure this out.

I am trying to move a PHP webapp from Plesk, to RunCloud. Both are hosted on a Digital Ocean server.

I exported the database from Plesk, and imported it into RunCloud. After updating the config, it only partially works. Some of the tasks read data, a few seem to write, but a majority just break it.

The strange thing is, if I point the config file to the Plesk server, the app works great using it as a remote database.

Here is from the PHPMyAdmin. The only thing that looks fishy is UNIX, vs TCP. But I cannot find a way to change RunCloud to UNIX.

I would copy the errors, but they are across the board. Any ideas? Thank you so much!

PHPMyAdmin Plesk Server:

```
Server: Localhost via UNIX socket
Server type: MariaDB
Server connection: SSL is not being used Documentation
Server version: 10.1.48-MariaDB-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 - Ubuntu 18.04
Protocol version: 10
User: prod@localhost
Server charset: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8mb4)
```

From RunCloud Server:

```
Server: 127.0.0.1 via TCP/IP
Server type: MariaDB
Server connection: SSL is not being used Documentation
Server version: 10.4.21-MariaDB-1:10.4.21+maria~focal-log - mariadb.org binary distribution
Protocol version: 10
User: prod@localhost
Server charset: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8)
```

Comment: 1) The two server versions are not exactly the same, your target version is older. You need to check if you are using any features included in the newer version, but not available in the target one. 2) Default character set is different between the two servers with target using the old utf8 encoding. 3) Without seeing the error messages it is impossible to help beyond this. There are tons of configuration settings that can break code between two mariadb instances, like enabling strict sql mode. Please do not expect anyone here to give you a full list of such settings.

Comment: Thank you so much! I started over on trying to figure it out based on you pointing out how different they actually were. After many hours again, I learned that 10.1 and 10.4 were rather different. I then went through each error to see if I could find the change on the MariaDB update guide (which is great). Somehow, I came across this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14625191/error-code-1292-incorrect-date-value-mysql. It was the zero date. I just added the line in my.cnf that it suggested. Fixed!!! OMG, Thank you! Couldn't have done it without your reply.

Answer (score 0):

As a newbie, I learned that 10.1 and 10.4 were rather different. I then went through each error to see if I could find the change on the MariaDB update guide (which is great). Somehow, I came across this post: [error code 1292 incorrect date value mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14625191/error-code-1292-incorrect-date-value-mysql). It was the zero date. I just added the line in my.cnf that it suggested. Fixed!!!