# Can not call the now() function inside a class

Tags: php, class

I can not call the `now()` function inside a class.

> Call to undefined function now()

How can I use the `now()` function?

```
class timeClass extends someClass
{
    public function update_login_time()
    {
        $time = now();
        return $time;
    }
}
```

Comment: `now()` is a mysql function. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_now See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1995562/now-function-in-php

Comment: try date function. go to [link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

Answer (score 6):

There's no `now()` function in PHP

You can use `date("Y-m-d H:i:s")` instead