# Why does call to now() fail in php

Tags: php

Why does call to now() or current_timestamp() fail in simple php script?

```
<?php
try {
    echo "Now: " . CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() . "<br>";
    //echo "Time: " . time() . "<br>";

    echo "Done";
}
catch(Exception $e) {
    echo 'Message: ' .$e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

The script returns a blank page, and no error is reported. time() worked fine.

Comment: What is `now()` and `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()`? Where are they defined?

Comment: Those are not PHP functions.

Comment: Well, not predefined PHP functions anyways.

Comment: I see. I read this post and it mentions those functions:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19246309/mysql-insert-current-date-time
So what file should I include?

Comment: That uestion is about SQL. In SQL you can use that. For PHP read php.net/date

Comment: That question doesn't have a `php` tag and PHP isn't anywhere on the page.

Comment: @ AbraCadaver: Good point!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`NOW()` and `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()` are MySQL functions, not PHP functions.

As [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1995562/now-function-in-php) suggests, the function you are looking for is `date("Y-m-d H:i:s")`. [Here is the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

Answer (score 2):

Your error should be something like

```
Call to undefined function CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()
```

[CURRENT_TIMESTAMP](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html)  is a synonym for [CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html) and [NOW()](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_now.asp) and they are **SQL functions**, from what I know (maybe they also have meaning in other contexts).

As such, if that format is what you are looking for just do:

```
date("Y-m-d H:i:s");//like 2014-11-22 12:45:34
```

---

Also check [this other SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1995562/now-function-in-php)

Comment: Any idea why I get no error message? I tried to add `error_reporting(E_ALL);` at top of script and still just get a blank page

Comment: @RaelB have you included `ini_set('display_errors', 1);`?

Comment: Thanks that solved it for me. I can see that the server default is 0 (off)