# Why does this block of code result in a blank space?

Tags: php

My goal is to subtract the two times and then generate a logged in checker from there.

What I need to know, is if I have correctly subtracted the two times in minutes.

PHP Version: 7.0

Time is entered into the DB using NOW() and shows as (Example: 2016-07-23 15:01:34)

For some reason, where this code is included in HTML, is just blank.

Code (everything is defined higher up in the code) :

```
<?php

include ('../includes/connection.php');
include ('../scripts/functions.php');

$getOnlineAdmins = $handler->prepare('SELECT * FROM Admins WHERE AdminLevel >= :al AND Status= :stat');
$statn = 1;
$aln = 1;
$getOnlineAdmins->bindParam(':al', $aln);
$getOnlineAdmins->bindParam(':stat', $statn);
$getOnlineAdmins->execute();

echo "
  <table class='table-fill'>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th class='text-left' style='padding-left: 12px; padding-right: 12px;';></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody class='table-hover'>";

if ($getOnlineAdmins->rowCount() >=1){
    echo ("These is one or more rows.");
    while ($results = $getOnlineAdmins->fetch()){
        if((strtotime($results['LastVisited']) + 900) >= time()){
            echo ("Time requirement met.");
            switch ($results['AdminLevel']) {
                case 3:
                    $rank = 'In-Training/Intern';
                    break;
                case 6:
                    $rank = 'Community Moderator';
                    break;
                case 9:
                    $rank = 'Senior Moderator';
                    break;
                case 12:
                    $rank = 'Supervisor';
                    break;
                case 15:
                    $rank = 'Administrator';
                    break;
                case 18:
                    $rank = 'Senior Administrator';
                    break;
                case 21:
                    $rank = 'Staff Advisor';
                    break;
                case 24:
                    $rank = 'Engineer';
                    break;
                case 27:
                    $rank = 'Vice Chairman';
                    break;
                case 30:
                    $rank = 'Chairman';
                    break;
                case 33:
                    $rank = 'Website Engineer';
                    break;
                default:
                    $rank = 'Unknown';
                    break;
            }
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>" . $results['Username'] . " - " . $rank . "</td>";
            } else {
            echo "<tr><td>{$results['Username']} &ndash; $rank</td>";
        }
    }
}else{
    echo "<tr><td>There are no staff members online.</td>";
}
echo " </tbody>
      </table>";

?>
```

Comment: What happens when you run it? Do you get expected results?

Comment: I do not get the expected result. This is the code, maybe I have a different error? http://pastebin.com/Abx176F2

Comment: I see many glaring errors. Where did this code come from?

Comment: I coded it myself...

Comment: The variables are assigned above all of that.

Comment: It's included into another page so there HTML above that too, which is why you see it at the bottom.

Comment: In what format is your time gathered?

Comment: Example: 2016-07-23 14:11:02

Comment: Turn on error reporting.

Comment: I entered error_reporting(E_ALL); and got nothing back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand it, `now()` is not getting the current time as you expect it to. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1995562/now-function-in-php) question for what I believe to be the root of your misunderstanding.

Assuming `$results['LastVisited']` is in the format `2016-07-23 14:11:02` – you could convert it to a UNIX timestamp with `strtotime`.

So if the time 15 minutes ago is less than or equal to your last visited time:

```
if (strtotime('-15 minutes') <= strtotime($results['LastVisited'])) {}
```

Alternative format with `time()` – that you would use instead of the MySQL equivalent `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()`:

```
if ((time() - 900) <= strtotime($results['LastVisited'])) {}
```

Comment: I am still having an issue. In this code http://pastebin.com/CT7MBLp0 (when it's included in the HTML), is simply returning blank. I have made sure everyone's status is set to 0, and it still will not return "nobody is online" like it should be. Also for further reference, here is the field. https://gyazo.com/15c5818e82aaa46f6a265cf289df2a2a

Comment: Can you `echo 'test';` in your `if` block successfully? And, under a successful subsequent if check, echo another string. Find out where your script is getting to, or not getting to. You should really use a `switch` instead of the massive if-else chain as well e.g. `switch ($results['AdminLevel'])` see [this](http://pastebin.com/raw/ntTDmrHA) example

Comment: This statement is not ran echo "<tr><td>There are no staff members online.</td>"; even when the status' are set to 0

Comment: Edited the post to show my new code. Nothing was echoed.

Comment: can you please debug your script. echo everywhere. See what is going on.

Comment: I think this answer has at least deserved your helpful upvote. I answered your question but you've managed to get issues elsewhere in the script. You can confirm that it is an answer by testing in isolation with dummy variables and dummy data. The only remaining advice I have is to ask you if you have instantiated `$rank` prior to the assignments made.

Comment: I've figured out the issue... it's got something to do with http://pastebin.com/PgBJLqfB