# Call to undefined function App\Http\Controllers\now() in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I'm receiving the following error in Laravel 5.2

The following is the query :

```
$ansrow = DB::table('answers')
         ->where('user_id', $u_id) 
         ->whereBetween('created_at', [
             now()->format('Y-m-d H:00:00'),
             now()->addHours(1)->format('Y-m-d H:00:00')
                    ])
          ->first();
```

I receive the following error :

```
Call to undefined function App\Http\Controllers\now()
```

Comment: There is no `now()` in PHP. You can do like the way mentioned in the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1995562/now-function-in-php/1995566

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `Carbon`, e.g.:

```php
$ansrow = DB::table('answers')
         ->where('user_id', $u_id) 
         ->whereBetween('created_at', [
             \Carbon\Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d H:00:00'),
             \Carbon\Carbon::now()->addHours(1)->format('Y-m-d H:00:00')
                    ])
          ->first();
```

And don't forget to assign the correct value to the `'timezone'` key in `config/app.php` or you'll get `UTC` datetime (`UTC` is the default).